# Sum of user login per user

Tags: sql

I am tracking the amount of times a user has logged in as well as the time logged in/out. So for example data would be:

```
USER       LOGGED IN     LOGGED OUT
-----------------------------------
DAVID      01/01/2015    02/01/2015
GEORGE     02/01/2015    02/01/2015
DAVID      04/01/2015    07/01/2015
PETER      10/01/2015    11/01/2015
DAVID      17/01/2015    18/01/2015
```

Now the query I am trying to create needs to return the following:

```
 USER       LOGGED_IN     LOGGED_OUT      SUM
---------------------------------------------
 DAVID      01/01/2015    02/01/2015       3
 DAVID      04/01/2015    07/01/2015       3
 DAVID      17/01/2015    18/01/2015       3
 GEORGE     02/01/2015    02/01/2015       1 
 PETER      10/01/2015    11/01/2015       1
```

The query at the moment is

```
select user, logged_in, logged_out
from login_records;
```

What can I change to this query to also display the total amount of entries of "user" as an additional column, without having to do another query? (for performance reasons)

Thanks.

Comment: Which database are you using?  There could be different answers depending...

Answer (score 3):

```
Select user, logged_in , logged_out, 
        count(*) over ( partition by user) as sum
from login_records t1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a correlated sub-query to your select:

```
select user, logged_in, logged_out, (select count(*) from login_records t2
                                     where t2.user = t1.user) as sum
from login_records t1;
```

Note that `user` is a reserved word in ANSI SQL, so you may need to delimit it as `"user"`, `t1."user"` etc.

Comment: But then I am doing another query aren't I?

Comment: Yes, of course that's another query. You can't get additional data "for free".

Comment: you kind of can with analytic functions

Comment: @sagi, I'm not quite sure I get you here. OP's query untouched, but still get more info?